# How to find out which file is being compiled currently in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

When Xcode Xcode compiles it displays something like `compiling 28 out of 68 source files`

How can I find out which file it is currently working on?

Comment: why you want to know that?

Comment: because compiling takes over 3h, and I like to know which files cause this...

Comment: The build log will update as it compiles each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, hit `cmd+7` to show log navigator, the top one is the log for current task, you can click the log and see the status. It will show which file are compiled and which one is compiling.

Comment: By the way, so when it shows a rather small file at the end it is done compiling and is doing the linking?

Comment: maybe it is a random but in the linker... you can try to compile the source file using command line. the log also shows the command executed and you can just copy and paste it to terminal to run it again.